# How to delete multiple Stored Procedures in One Database

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, select, stored-procedures

I am using SQL Server 2008. I have a database `Training` which contains two types of stored procedures with names prefixed by `SP_V400_` and `spV400_`. Now I need to delete the stored procedures with the name prefix `spV400_`.

I tried this command

```
SELECT 'DROP PROCEDURE [' + SCHEMA_NAME(p.schema_id) + '].[' + p.NAME + '] GO'
FROM sys.procedures p  
WHERE p.name LIKE '%spV400%'
ORDER BY p.name
```

But I am getting an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.

Comment: http://www.devasp.net/net/articles/display/309.html

Comment: USE spV400% NOT %spV400%.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need the GO at the end.

Try this:

```
SELECT 'DROP PROCEDURE [' + SCHEMA_NAME(p.schema_id) + '].[' + p.NAME + ']'
FROM sys.procedures p  WHERE p.name like 'spV400%'
ORDER BY p.name
```

That of course will give you a list of SQL commands in the output which you can copy and paste into SSMS and run.

Comment: Incidentally the filter won't find SP_V400.

Comment: I found this a very useful query!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 'DROP PROCEDURE [' + SCHEMA_NAME(p.schema_id) + '].[' + p.NAME + ']' as column into #tmptable 
FROM sys.procedures p  WHERE p.name like 'spV400%' 
ORDER BY p.name
declare @deleteAll nvarchar(max)
select @deleteAll = coalesce(@deleteAll + '; ', + '') + #tmptable.column from #tmptable
EXEC sp_executesql @deleteAll
drop table #tmptable
```

This will insert all the stored procedure names in the temp table and then convert them in semicolon separated value and drop all stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

1    Click on Stored Procedures Tab

2    Filter Store Procedures Using Filter Functionality of SQL

3    Select All Procedure By Ctrl + A except System Table

4    Press Delete button and Click OK.

or Find the link http://www.devasp.net/net/articles/display/309.html

Answer (score 0):

**GO** is not a SQL cmd, its a windows batch terminator.
So it needs to be in separate line always. All you need to do so is to include **char(10)** in your code for line feed.

```
SELECT 'DROP PROCEDURE [' + SCHEMA_NAME(p.schema_id) + '].[' + p.NAME + ']'+char(10)+'GO'
FROM sys.procedures p  WHERE p.name like '%spV400%'
ORDER BY p.name
```

Execute the above code and copy paste the resultset in a query window for execution with **GO** keyword.

Comment: This won't work because the GO statement is still in the middle of the SQL statement, making it syntactically incorrect.  If you really need a GO it should be at the end on a new line after the ORDER BY.

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach,

```
select 'DROP PROCEDURE ' + ROUTINE_SCHEMA + '.' + SPECIFIC_NAME
from    YourDBName.information_schema.routines 
where   routine_type = 'PROCEDURE' AND SPECIFIC_NAME like '%test%'
```

copy the result and execute. that's all.